# prediction argument in ROCR

Tags: r, prediction, roc

I am trying to plot a ROC curve with ROCR in order to assess the goodness of fit of a binomial logit model. (my database is named "stat")
I correctly obtain the model through:

```
GLM.4 <- glm(V1 ~ V10 + V11 + V13 + V14 + V15, family=binomial(logit), 
  data=stat)
summary(GLM.4)
exp(coef(GLM.4))
```

But when I run the ROCR commands:

```
GLM.4.pred <- prediction(GLM.4, stat, label.orderin=NULL)
perf <- performance(GLM.4.pred, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(perf)
```

I always obtain the error "Number of cross-validation runs must be equal for predictions and labels."

Could someone help me on understanding the error?
Thank you

Comment: Could you provide a subset of stat?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
GLM.4 <- glm(V1 ~ V10 + V11 + V13 + V14 + V15, family=binomial(link=logit), data=stat)
```

The documentation for family indicates that "link" is not the default destination for the value.
If that does not work, what does a summary of GLM.4 look like?

Comment: tried your suggestion, but at the line

GLM.4.pred <- prediction(GLM.4, stat, label.orderin=NULL)

I obtain the same error.

Comment: The summary of GLM.4 is:
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.0363  -0.5375  -0.3892  -0.3020   3.2103  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.655e+00  7.753e-02 -21.342  < 2e-16 ***
V10         -1.815e-04  1.871e-05  -9.701  < 2e-16 ***
V11         -1.264e-01  1.608e-02  -7.861 3.82e-15 ***
V13         -3.524e-02  6.532e-03  -5.395 6.87e-08 ***
V14         -1.480e-02  1.588e-03  -9.319  < 2e-16 ***
V15          1.248e-01  1.525e-02   8.181 2.81e-16 ***
---